# Changing type of battery from lead acid to lipo in a motorcycle

Tags: voltage-regulator, charging, lipo

I have a 80cc scooter with only electric start and a weak battery.....in a perfect world ide say buy a new a150 dollar battery and put into my 59 dollar scooter...   I have jumped it with a 3c lipo rc pack before and started fine..how could i with the different voltages between lead acid and lipo and scooter charging system, hard wire permanently the pack into the bike?  Lots of spare lipos i have..money i do not...

3 lipo batteris in series is a total of 12.6 volts.  The output of vehicle is between 13.3 and 14.4 volts which would destroy battery.  My plan is to use a combination of diodes in series to bring the max voltage down to 12.6, then use one large diode with as little a voltage drop, and as high a current capacity, as possible, facing the other way for when the circuit is in a discharge state ( starting).  I am sure thier may be many other ways to accomolish this as well, and would like your feedback and advice.

Also, since the primary battery has about had it, might be a good time for a science experiment: has anyone had any success with rejuvinating a lead acid battery? Does epsom salt work?   And if it does, what are the mecanics of it? How would it cause the sulfates to either become conductively innert, or put them back into solution altogether ?

Comment: Please edit your post for content and readability. I made a start on your first paragraph, but there's still a *lot* needed, especially in para. 2. - Also, this question is likely to be closed as "too broad," since you haven't really given us one concise, specific, answerable question to give you answers to. Please try to be as clear and specific as possible. (right now it somewhat sounds more like musings, than an engineering question)

Comment: Better? Engish was never my strong suit. I do appoligize.

Comment: Now, in reference to your problem(s): For this you'd end up having to install a dedicated LiPO/Li-ion/LiFePO (whichever your batteries *actually* are) charging circuit to your bike. Each one of the 3 series cells has to have some way of *balancing* with the others; you *should* make it at least 3S2P in order to *safely* handle all the current draw that is required. -- While Lead-Acid batteries don't mind being overcharged, and can be recovered from over-discharging, Lithium-chemistry batteries can be quickly *destroyed* by either, so you *must* use dedicated circuitry for them.

Comment: Not better. You simply made it back to what it impossible to read, same as first. If you put 5 spaces in front of a paragraph, the site places it in as codeblock & *all* textx get put into lines with *no* automatic returns added. I intended the first paragraph to be an example of how to improve your formatting, but you reverted every improvement I made. ... Voting to close.

Comment: There might be a better place to ask this type of question in regards to your motorcycle. The [Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair StackExchange](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/) would be a more appropriate place to ask.

Comment: I understand the balancing problem...and the need for individual dedicated per cell charging.  But as a get by stop gap measure, though itll decrease life, just going to group charge..now if i use inline diodes to reduce max voltage to 12.6 (thats is the 4.2 per cell)  similar to lead acid, wont the battery begin ti deminish draw and eventually not take any current at all when fully charged, assuming i do not exceed the 4.2 per cell?

Answer (score 1):

Do not even think of substituting some LiPo battery back for the lead acid battery.  The charging system on the scooter or motor cycle is completely incompatible with LiPo battery technology. In the luckiest case you will destroy the battery and in the worst case the LiPo will explode and catch fire.

Special charging circuitry would be required and I pretty much guess that by the time you would get that under your belt and have one built you will be way over the cost of the proper replacement battery.

Answer (score 0):

The replacement you can do is for a LiFePO4, there are some comercially available batteries [UPG Phantom Series](https://www.1000bulbs.com/pdf/upg-phantom-motorcycle-batteries.pdf) which are design for such purpose. 
I heard from a battery representative that is batteries will work as a complete equivalent to the seal lead acid battery and will work with the stock charging system. I could recommend contact them and ask about your specific application to see if they can be a match.

Comment: Yes, i do know about the new lipo for auto applications....their awesome..light and small with same or more current.  Great for racing.  The real question is they had to deal with and answer the same queation i am.  I have the lipos.....but the voltage is at stock, incompatible.....so i am curious to their approach to it.

Comment: Well, the these are not LiPo but Lithium Iron Phosphate, they are still part of the Lithium battery but they are quite different compared to LiPO, LiFePO4 are more tolerant to overcharging and discharging to LiPO so much that LiFePO4 is consider "safe". Additionally the nominal voltage for this batteries is 3.2V so four cells would leave you at 12.8V and the maximum cell voltage s 3.65V so at max that would say 14.6V in a 4 cell battery making it compatible with most stock systems